# Best way to run a Plack PSGI Perl application outside of Apache using FastCGI?

Tags: apache, perl, fastcgi, plack, psgi

I'm currently running Apache/mod_perl with a PSGI-application invoked by Plack::Handler::Apache2. The problem we have is each Apache process consumes a connection to the PostgreSQL database, which is expensive. To solve this, we plan to run the PSGI-application separate from Apache, and let all Apache processes communicate with it over a UNIX domain socket. What setup would you recommend in my case?

My plan is to run it using plackup:

```
plackup -s FCGI -E production --nproc 100 --daemonize --listen /tmp/myapp.sock \
/usr/local/bin/myapp.psgi
```

I asked the author of Plack, Tatsuhiko Miyagawa, if plackup -s FCGI is recommended for production purposes. He provided the following answer:

> "while it could be used for production, i usually recommend using other
>   specialized servers such as Starman, Starlet or uwsgi. FCGI is an
>   exception because we don't have a specific FCGI daemon other than the
>   default Plack::Handler. We have a plan to split out FCGI out of Plack
>   core and make that a separate installation."

Now, until FCGI is splitted out of Plack, the question is therefore, what is the best possible way to run a PSGI application using FastCGI outside of Apache?

Comment: I would consider posting this question in Perl's IRC channel. They can be more helpful than you think. :) Good luck.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use FCGI instead of running your seperate Plack webserver and using ProxyPass from Apache?

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using the FastCGI protocol, you can make Apache connect to an external FastCGI server using `mod_fastcgi` and the `FastCgiExternalServer` directive (note that `mod_fcgid` does *not* support this mode of operation). This should work with the FCGI handler built into Plack.

But as Tatsuhiko said, it's recommended to use a server like Starman or Starlet that works as reverse proxy over HTTP. So you would use `mod_proxy` on the Apache side. With Apache 2.4.7, it's also possible to [communicate over Unix domain sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648515/apache-to-psgi-proxy-over-a-unix-domain-socket).